# CakePHP 2.x - Custom Routes

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I have two controllers: ArtistsController and RecordsController

I want to order routes logically depending on what the user is doing.

In this case once the user is editing an Artist (/artists/edit/some-artist) he's able to add some records for that artist.

So, I'd like the route to be something like:
***"/artists/edit/some/artist/records/add"***

And the same thing with the editing function of a record:
***"/artists/edit/some-artist/records/edit/some-record"***

I've been fighting with it for a while but I've never worked with Routes before on CakePHP and can't find a solution for this. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In **Config/routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/artists/edit/:some_artist', array('controller' => 'artists', 'action' => 'edit'), array('pass' => array('some_artist')));
Router::connect('/artists/edit/:some_artist/:records', array('controller' => 'artists', 'action' => 'edit'), array('pass' => array('some_artist','records')));
```

and you go on depending how what parameters you want to pass.

rule is simple: is some variable needs to be passed you put colon ":" before it, and add its name in array 'pass'.

I suggest read [Routing: Route elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements) if you want specify type of passing element.

Additionally **Artists Controller** function should like this

```
public function edit($some_artist=null,$records = null) {
/**
[...]
*/
}
```